# Inclusive checkbox list (Automatically checking boxes below selected box)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I am making a form where there is a list of permissions available to the user. Each permission is a checkbox. (Therefore, there is a list of checkboxes!)

The permissions are inclusive... The top element of the list gives access to itself as well as the ones below it.

I am trying to model this using the forms UI. I would like the checkboxes below a checked box to automatically check themselves when a box is checked above them.

The problem is I can't figure out how to do it using javascipt or jquery. I can run functions when the boxes are toggled, but I can't figure out how to check the following boxes in the DOM.

---

*HTML CODE FOR BUTTONS:*

```
<div class="account_edit">
  <a name="edit_permissions"><h2>Edit Permissions</h2></a>
  <form action="/admin/account-modify/permissions/" method="POST">
    <h3>Request permission change:</h3>
    <span>(all items below selected permission level are included)</span>

    <h4>Admin</h4>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="0">manage users
    <br/>

    <h4>Manager</h4>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="1">view users
    <br/>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="2">view students
    <br/>

    <h4>Editor</h4>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="3">manage new stories
    <br/>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="4">manage videos
    <br/>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="5">manage pictures
    <br/>

    <h4>Reporter</h4>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="6">upload news stories
    <br/>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="7">upload videos
    <br/>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="8">upload pictures
    <br/>

    <h4>User</h4>
    <input class="radio" type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="10">manage your account
    <br/>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Request Change">
    <br/>
    <a class="cancel" href="#">cancel</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: And what's your question? what have you tried? where are you stuck? also please include the relevant code in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    $(this).nextAll('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xAxXK/

---

If you want your code to be a little more efficient, you can use this longer snippet with less DOM travesal:

```
var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

checkboxes.change(function () {

    var index = checkboxes.index(this);
    var isChecked = this.checked;

    checkboxes.each(function (i, el) {
        if ( i > index ) el.checked = isChecked;
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xAxXK/1/

Comment: Great! The only thing it could use it unchecking the previous boxes. but otherwise, perfect!

Comment: @NathanPetersen - Which version are you using? I can help you out with that.

Comment: @NathanPetersen - Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/xAxXK/2/ . Again, this can be made more efficient, but if you prefer the succinctness of this solution, go for it.